# Does Google Play internal testing require testers to "verify your age" in order to download apps?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I have created an app for Google Play and established an "internal testing" test track. I added a new Gmail account as a tester. However, when attempting to install the app, I encounter a screen requesting me to verify my age before proceeding. This is undesirable as I only intend to use this account for testing purposes. The app is labeled as "unreviewed." Is there a way to download the app for testing without undergoing the "verify your age" process?

Comment: I have some old accounts that were created without birth date, they don't trigger age verification in internal testing. However when creating new google account I see there is now no option to skip giving birth date and these accounts trigger age verification in case you mentioned. Yea it sucks, I don't want test accounts to have my personal data or credit cards linked. I thought about using prepaid visa gift cards for verification, but idk how viable this workaround is.